# Copy column values via X++ based on comparing values

Tags: axapta, x++, data-conversion

Currently i have 3 tables.

KEV_PackTable
KEV_Persons
HcmWorkerRecId

I am phasing out the KEV_Persons table, which currently has a relation:

Kev_PackTable.PersonId -> KEV_Persons.PersonId

Instead of this table, i want to use the HcmWorker table, making a relationship:
Kev_PackTable.HcmWorker_RecId -> HcmWorker.RecId

If KEV_PackTable.Personid is the same value as HcmWorker.PersonnelNumber, then fill in the RecId of that row into the column: HcmWorker_RecId in the table: KEV_PackTable.

It is more a query question than a AX2012 question, but I can't find the solution to fill in the RecId when the Personid matches the PersonnelNumber value.

I think my SQL statement has to be:

```
UPDATE KEV_PackTable
SET HcmWorkerRecId = HcmWorker.RecId
FROM KEV_PackTable
JOIN HcmWorker
ON KEV_PackTable.PersonId = HcmWorker.PersonnelNumber
```

How can i run this query in X++? Do I start with a select forUpdate statement?

Comment: Could you show us the code/query you have tried so far? I would rather help you find the problems in your existing code than give you a copy&paste answer.

Comment: Sure! I have edited my original post.

Comment: In your table listing (2nd line) the last table HcmWorkerRecId should probably be HcmWorker, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got everything right then this code should work for you using [update_recordset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa674382.aspx) so that you have the chance of performing a bulk update

```
KEV_PackTable packTable;
HcmWorker     hcmWorker;
;

update_recordset packTable
    setting HcmWorkerRecId = hcmWorker.RecId
    join firstOnly RecId from hcmWorker
        where hcmWorker.PersonnelNumber == packTable.PersonId;
```

An alternative solution would be using `while select forUpdate` like so

```
KEV_PackTable packTable;
HcmWorker     hcmWorker;
;

ttsbegin;
while select forUpdate packTable
    join firstOnly RecId from hcmWorker
        where hcmWorker.PersonnelNumber == packTable.PersonId
{
    // ttsbegin;
    packTable.HcmWorkerRecId = hcmWorker.RecId;
    packTable.update();
    // ttscommit;
}
ttscommit;
```

With this you can - depending on your needs - switch to multiple smaller transactions (by commenting out the outer `ttsbegin`/`ttscommit` and using the inner ones) which will probably increase the total execution time but may lead to fewer blocked sessions.